# Showing that $\int_{0}^{1} f\, \overline{g} \,dx$ isn't an inner product on $C[0,2]$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing

My reasoning is just that the inner products on $C[0,2]$ are defined to be the integrals from $0$ to $2$… and the one in the problem is from $0$ to $1$, so it can’t be an inner product based on that. Is this reasoning too simplistic or even incorrect? I don’t see any other way to show that it’s not an inner product on $C[0,2]$.

Comment: In order to show that it isn't an inner product you have to show that is doesn't satisfy the properties of an inner product i.e.: 1) bilinearity, 2) symmetry and 3) positive definiteness. In your particular case you can easily show that 3) is not fullfilled

Comment: @StiftungWarentest Right, I know that that's the usual process, but why doesn't my reasoning work out in this case? I'd appreciate some insight.

Comment: Your statement "the inner products on $C[0,2]$ are defined to be the integrals from $0$ to $2$" is imprecise at best. You could e.g. define an inner product as $\int_0^1 \left(f(x)\overline{g(x)}+f(2-x)\overline{g(2-x)}\right)dx$

Comment: An inner product requires that $\langle f , f \rangle = 0$ iff $f = 0$, in this case, since you are integrating from 0 to 1, the integral of $f^2$ implies $f=0$ on the interval [0,1] but you can't say anthing for [1,2].

Comment: BTW, @StiftungWarentest gives a nice example, but there are also plenty more: Pick a basis (which will be huge and ugly and delivered to us by the axiom of choice or something equivalent), declare it to be orthonormal, and extend to the rest of the space by the properties of a basis.

Comment: 3 hours have passed and I understand nothing..

Comment: @Franlezana If that’s the proof I don’t understand it

Comment: @Mista It's not the proof but the idea of a proof, in order to show that $\int_0^1 f \overline{g}$ is not an inner product on $C[0,2]$ you need to find a continuous function $f$ such that $\langle f, f \rangle =\int_0^1 f^2  = 0$ but $f \neq 0$ . An example of such a function could be $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and $f(x) = x-1$ for $x \in [1,2]$ this function is continuous and satisfies that $\langle f, f \rangle = 0$ but the function is not $0$

Comment: @Franlezana Oh ok. So a continuous piecewise function like you just described would suffice?

Comment: @Mista yes, that's enough

Comment: Try to prove that $\langle (x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\rangle = x_1\bar y_1$ is not an inner product on $\mathbb C^2$ first.

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning boils down to the following argument: "The inner products on function spaces I've seen are of the form X. This is not of the form X, so it is not an inner product on a function space."

Generalizing, you are essentially saying: "I'm used to <type of object> looking like X. So all <type of object>s must look like X".

This kind of reasoning is called inductive, and it is essential for the sciences, where the rules of our universe are carved in stone, but we don't know them and we try to find or at least approximate those rules by making many observations and then assuming that what was true for all of our observations until now will probably be true in general.

This is not how reasoning in math works. Mathematical reasoning is generally deductive, that is, we *know* the rules because we set them ourselves, and now we want to find out what we can do with those rules.

That is, in maths you have to work with the rules that we set ourselves. In this case the rules are: Inner products are sesquilinear, symmetric and positive definite. You have to appeal to these rules, not your previous experiences. Your previous experiences may inform you about how to work with the rules, but you can't appeal to them when making your final argument.

Here specifically, it is a basic exercise to prove that the given operation is not positive definite: Try to find a nonzero functions $f$ such that $\int_0^1f(x)\bar f(x)\mathrm dx=0$. Use the fact that the integral from 0 to 1 doesn't depend on how the function behaves on $(1,2)$.

Comment: I appreciate that you showed me the error in my thinking and the difference between inductive and deductive reasoning. But telling me that it's easy doesn't make it easy for me.

Comment: I'm sorry if that was demotivating, and I changed how I wrote it. Though I'm not going to sugarcoat it: Exercises of the type "Check wether the basic axioms we're going to be working with are satisfied" are comparatively going to be on the easy side. You should get comfortable with this thought.

Comment: small correction: integral from $0$ to $0$ should be integral from $0$ to $1$ in your last sentence of the post.